# How to merge multiple excel sheet with the same name from different workbooks and save into a new excel workbook using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Need some help on merging excel file with the same sheet name from multiple workbooks and saving it in a new workbook.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

path = "C:/Users/"
fname = glob.glob(path + "\*.xlsx")
print(fname)

mfile = pd.DataFrame()
result_DFs = []

for i in fname:
    
    df = pd.read_excel(i,sheet_name = None)
    
    for sheet in df:

        if (sheet == "Owner and Status each sheet"):
            result = result_DFs.append(df[sheet])
```

After this I'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: Each Excel file has one single sheet ?

Comment: @M92_ , it has multiple excel sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code will append the data in **result_DFs** from tabname "Owner and Status each sheet" from all workbooks present in the given path;

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r"C:\Users"
fname = glob.glob(path + "\*.xlsx")

result_DFs = pd.DataFrame()
for i in fname:  
    try:
        df = pd.read_excel(i,sheet_name = "Owner and Status each sheet")
                result_DFs = pd.concat([result_DFs,df])
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: `append` is [deprecated and will be removed](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#whatsnew-140-deprecations-frame-series-append)